# purrr loop through columns of one dataframe and conditionally replace values from another dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, purrr

With the following data...

```
library(tidyverse)

df_fac <- data_frame("author_1" = c("Ted", "Fred", NA, "Jim", "Tim"), 
                 "role_1" = c("Faculty", "Faculty", "Staff", "Faculty", "Faculty"),
                 "author_2" = c(NA, "Will", NA, "Bill", NA),
                 "role_2" = c("Staff", "Faculty", "Staff", "Faculty", "Staff"))

df_all <- data_frame("author_1" = c("Ted", "Fred", "Simon", "Jim", "Tim"), 
                     "role_1" = c("Faculty", "Faculty", "Staff", "Faculty", "Faculty"),
                     "author_2" = c("Sam", "Will", "Noah", "Bill", "Luther"),
                     "role_2" = c("Staff", "Faculty", "Staff", "Faculty", "Staff"))
```

If the "author" columns in `df_fac` are `NA`, I would like them to get filled in with the corresponding column value from `df_all` using a `map` function from `purrr`.  This is what I currently do without a loop:

```
df_test <- df_fac %>%
  mutate(`author_1` = ifelse(is.na(`author_1`), df_all$`author_1`, `author_1`)) %>%
  mutate(`author_2` = ifelse(is.na(`author_2`), df_all$`author_2`, `author_2`))
```

With `map_df` I can do this iterating over the columns in `df_fac`, but not in `df_all` (As you can see it's only author column 1).

```
df_test <- map_df(select(df_fac, matches("author.\\d$")), ~ {
  ifelse(is.na(.), df_all$`author_1`, .)
})
```

Is there a way to have `map_df` iterate over `select(df_all, matches("author.\\d$"))` while it iterates over `select(df_fac, matches("author.\\d$"))`?

With the toy example, `df_test` should have the same author columns and values as `df_all`.  I have tried:

```
df_test <- map_df(1:length(select(df_fac, matches("author.\\d$"))), ~ {
  ifelse(is.na(select(df_fac, matches("author.\\d$"))[.]), 
  select(df_all, matches("author.\\d$"))[.], 
  select(df_fac, matches("author.\\d$"))[.])
})
```

Throws `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : not compatible with STRSXP`

```
df_test <- pmap_chr(list(is.na(select(df_fac, matches("author.\\d$"))), 
                         select(df_all, matches("author.\\d$")), 
                         select(df_fac, matches("author.\\d$"))), 
                    ifelse)
```

Throws `Error: Element 2 has length 2, not 1 or 10.`

I need to use the `matches` function as the actual data has a lot of author columns mixed in with similar variable names.  I can clarify if this is not clear.  Thank you.

Comment: In your example, it seems you want your `df_test` output to be identical to `df_all`. Could you improve it to better reflect your real data, and what the problem is? Also: `map` is great but are you sure it suits your needs? Maybe a `*_join()` or something else is more appropriate

Comment: @apom The code chunk with the 2 `mutate` calls is exactly what I'm trying to do, but using a loop.  In the real data there are columns and values in `df_fac` that are not in `df_all` and vice versa, hence my example above needing to bring in missing author names.  There isn't really any problem with the way I do it now, it's just a lot of repetitive code (I do the same thing with a few other variables, which ends up being about 24 very similar looking `mutate` calls).

Comment: Ok, one more question: can we safely assume that `df_fac` and `df_all` are ordered identically? If we somehow `cbind()` them, will their rows always match? Or is there a variable to join by?

Comment: Have you looked at `map2` for looping through two lists simultaneously?

Comment: @apom Yes they are ordered identically

Comment: @aosmith Yes I am just not sure how that would look (as you can see with my `pmap_chr` try I used the 3 arguments in `ifelse`, but came up with an error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map2_df` for looping through two lists simultaneously.  Using `dplyr::coalsece` will help in replacing the missing values.  I used `select` to make sure the columns in `df_all` were the same and in the same order as `df_fac`.

```
map2_df(df_fac, select(df_all, one_of(names(df_fac))), ~coalesce(.x, .y))
```

Same thing using `pmap`:

```
pmap_df(list(df_fac, select(df_all, one_of(names(df_fac)))), coalesce)
```

You can use `ifelse` with `map2`, as well, along with formula notation to refer to the two different lists you are using.

```
map2_df(df_fac, select(df_all, one_of(names(df_fac))), 
       ~ifelse(is.na(.x), .y, .x))
```

Comment: This is pretty awesome.  Had to futz with some subsetting with the original data, but this is a nice solution. Thank you for the `map2` lesson.